# Where did my pop-up window go to?

Tags: java, selenium

The case of the disappearing pop-up window!

I click a link and it is supposed to bring up a little dialog pop-up window where I can change the State (like MA, VA, etc). I then would click OK, the pop-up window would disappear and I'd be back on the main window having fun with wild abandon.

That's what happens when I do it manually. When I do it through my nifty Selenium Java project the link gets clicked a pop-up window briefly appears then poof! It's gone and I mean really gone, not just in the background.

Here's a code sniipet:

```
 WebElement foo4 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("State:"));
 String myText;
 myText = foo4.getText();
 System.out.println("I got: " + myText);
 foo4.click();

 (do stuff in the pop-up window down here)
```

I threw a println in there to make absolutely sure that foo4 really is the link to be clicked and it is! Sanity checks help sometimes.

When the click event happens, poof! That pop-up window shows kinda like a ghost for a split second totally blank and then it's gone. I have no idea what's happening. It IS intermittent. 10% of the time the pop-up window does appear but most of the time no dice.

I'm open to ideas here. It's not a matter of cycling through the available windows yet, I only have a main window so that's not even in the picture yet.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is your dialog pop-up a `div` container inside the page or a new browser window?

Comment: It's a new browser window.

Comment: You need to set the context on that new window to interact with it `driver.switchTo().window`. I think that the main window is automatically closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking the element, scrape the `href` or similar attribute that holds the URL, then do `driver.get(url);` or whatever it looks like in Java.

That way you can navigate to the URL in the main browser window and do what you need to do there.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and see, that just may work, I'll have to see.

Comment: This is going to sound REALLY weird but I believe it's a browser history issue. I say that because I just had it happen again after it working fine all morning. I went in and cleared my browser history and Shazam! It works perfectly. I have no proof of this other than my own experience. I don't know if this makes any sense. Now if I could figure out a way to automatically clear the browser history.

Comment: @PeterCook, What browser are you using?  Have you experimented with other browsers?  You may have better luck with a different `WebDriver` if the issue is browser-specific.  This would also enable you to determine if the issue is the browser history/cache or whatever.

Comment: That's my next step.